# List part of arraylist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have abstract class A. Class B inherits from A, and class C inherits from B.

- Class A has two instance variables **string firstName**, and **string lastName**
- Class B does not have instance variables.
- Class C has one instance variable int age.

I create function to list all object in the list. My ArrayList is created from Class B, and C.

I want to create a function just list object has age (object from class C). How?

Comment: provide code, please, hard to read these explanation

Comment: you can check if the element from the list is an instance of class C, eg: `if(element instanceof C){((C)element).age}`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to simply check the type of each object in your list:

```
for (Object item : yourListWithBAndCs) {
      if (item instanceof C) {
           C itemAsC = (C) item;
           // do something
      } else { ... }
}
```

Starting with Java8, you can use of streams and filters (Kudos to @Andrew Tobilko) for this suggestion:

```
list.stream().filter(i -> i instanceof C).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above will create a new list for you; containing only those objects that are instances of C.

Comment: Still need to cast `item` to `C`

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: or `list.stream.filter(i -> i instanceof C).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Thanks, too: I am not yet into the streams stuff, but it is definitely worth mentioning here!

Answer (score -2):

```
class C extends B
{
     int age;
     ArrayList listAge;
     C()
     {
        listAge = new ArrayList();
     }
     public void addAge()
     {
    listAge.add(age);          
     }
}
```

Comment: Donot forget to import java.util.*;

Comment: That is not what he asking for. He has **one** list with different objects, and he wants to "filter" out those belonging to B.